# Unable to copy file "obj\Debug..\GENERIC_APP_NAME\PAGENAME.xaml"

Tags: c#, hyperlink, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a generic Windows METRO style app that is supposed to be a base application for derived applications (with different styles, resources, etc...)

So in order to use this generic app, I've added an other app in my solution where almost all files are links to files from my generic app, including pages.

But when I try to compile the derived, I get the following error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug..\GENERIC_APP_NAME\PAGENAME.xaml"

I guess this has something to do with msbuild tool that doesn't copy the linked files to the right place.

Is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks guys.

Comment: That was a good idea, but that is not it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I asked the same question on Microsoft Forums.
This is a Visual Studio 2012 RC bug.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/cda8690c-f98f-49ca-af96-bcc69efe5a1d